# DPLL algorithm definition

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I am having some problems understanding the DPLL algorithm and I was wondering if anyone could explain it to me because I think my understanding is incorrect.

The way I understand it is, I take some set of literals and if some every clause is true the model is true but if some clause is false then the model is false.

I recursively check the model by looking for a unit clause, if there is one I set the value for that unit clause to make it true, then update the model. Removing all clauses that are now true and remove all literals which are now false.

When there are no unit clauses left, I chose any other literal and assign values for that literal which make it true and make it false, then again remove all clauses which are now true and all literals which are now false.

Comment: I honestly don't see how this question is any different than the previous, or adds anything else.  It looks instead like you've read the n+1th answer and now finally feel satisfied, but this still read as a duplicate to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DPLL requires a problem to be stated in disjunctive normal form, that is, as a set of clauses, each of which must be satisfied.

Each clause is a set of literals `{l1, l2, ..., ln}`, representing the disjunction of those literals (i.e., at least one literal must be true for the clause to be satisfied).

Each literal `l` asserts that some variable is true (`x`) or that it is false (`~x`).

If any literal is true in a clause, then the clause is satisfied.

If all literals in a clause are false, then the clause is unsatisfiable and hence the problem is unsatisfiable.

A solution is an assignment of true/false values to the variables such that every clause is satisfied.  The DPLL algorithm is an optimised search for such a solution.

DPLL is essentially a depth first search that alternates between three tactics.  At any stage in the search there is a partial assignment (i.e., an assignment of values to some subset of the variables) and a set of undecided clauses (i.e., those clauses that have not yet been satisfied).

(1) The first tactic is Pure Literal Elimination: if an unassigned variable `x` only appears in its positive form in the set of undecided clauses (i.e., the literal `~x` doesn't appear anywhere) then we can just add `x = true` to our assignment and satisfy all the clauses containing the literal `x` (similarly if `x` only appears in its negative form, `~x`, we can just add `x = false` to our assignment).

(2) The second tactic is Unit Propagation: if all but one of the literals in an undecided clause are false, then the remaining one must be true.  If the remaining literal is `x`, we add `x = true` to our assignment; if the remaining literal is `~x`, we add `x = false` to our assignment.  This assignment can lead to further opportunities for unit propagation.

(3) The third tactic is to simply choose an unassigned variable `x` and branch the search: one side trying `x = true`, the other trying `x = false`.

If at any point we end up with an unsatisfiable clause then we have reached a dead end and have to backtrack.

There are all sorts of clever further optimisations, but this is the core of almost all SAT solvers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good explanation.  The OP's question suggests s/he may be missing that your 3rd tactic is "tentative" -- i.e. in that case we conceptually need to "save" before trying one assignment and be prepared to "restore" and try the other assignment in case it fails downstream.  (While OTOH tactics 1 and 2 always work and never need to be undone, except when they occur after a usage of tactic 3 which itself needs to be undone.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker, do you mean for part 3, you try false then try true, not true and false? How do you know which to keep and which to disregard?

Comment: @Rafe, you say that if at any point we end up with an unsatisfiable clause then we have to backtrack, but earlier you said that if there is an unsatisfiable clause then the problem is unsatisfiable, which is it? I am a bit confused. Thanks.

Comment: @Neutralise: Whether you guess "true" first or "false" first for part 3 doesn't matter -- all that matters is that, if after trying one of them you later encounter unsatisfiability, you need to *backtrack* to when you made this decision and try the other way.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, so for case 3, if there is a clause which ever becomes false, then I need to go all the way back to when I started with the literal that caused this clause and change its value? Sorry I am a bit confused by this, wouldnt that mean I have to remember every single point of insertion for each literal? How would the entire set of clauses ever be found false if I continually backtrack?

Comment: @Neutralise: the algorithm is conducting a search for a solution.  A solution in this case is a true/false assignment to all the variables in the problem such that all the clauses are satisfied.  Part of the search process is conducting experiments: given the choices I've made so far, should x69 be true or false?  If I have a choice, then I have to try both options to see which work.  Think of exploring a maze: when you come to a junction, you have a choice point.  So you make a choice.  If you reach a dead end, you have to backtrack to the last choicepoint and try a different option.

Comment: @Neutralise: re: unsatisfiability, what I mean is that IF I pick an (partial) assignment that makes a clause false THEN this assignment cannot be part of a solution.

Comment: @Neutralise: At any given point during the search, we have a set of assignments of values to variables.  Initially that set is empty; each application of rule 1, 2 or 3 creates a new state containing more assignments.  Think of the search as building a linked list of states hanging down from the initial (empty) state.  We are always looking at the current (bottom) node and deciding what to do next.  If it's possible to apply rule 1 or 2, we do that, producing a new state that hangs at the bottom and becomes the new current state...

Comment: ...   If not, but rule 3 can be applied, let's say to variable x, we arbitrarily pick one value (say "true") and add a new state containing x=true to the end of the linked list.  But immediately before adding this new state, *we stick a post-it note on the current node saying "Try x=false"*.  The purpose of the post-it note is this: Whenever we reach a state containing an unsatisfiable clause, instead of giving up right away, we start climbing up the linked list looking for post-it notes.  If we get to the top without finding one, *then* we say "It's unsatisfiable!".  But if we do find one...

Comment: ... while climbing up the linked list, we immediately stop and do whatever it says on the post-it note -- i.e. we resume the search at this point, adding another node to the bottom that makes the opposite choice from what we made the first time.  We throw the post-it note in the rubbish as soon as we have begun doing what it says.  If you try some toy examples on paper you should be able to convince yourself that this will always do the right thing, and always terminate eventually.

Comment: Thanks alot for your explanation I think I understand now and I will try and make an implementation. Thanks again.

Comment: @Rafe: I'm not  sure why you differentiate between steps 1 and 2.  In most presentations of DPLL they are t he same, as long as you define unit propagation correctly...

Comment: @KristopherMicinski: really?  I've always read PLE described separately from UP.  If you don't do PLE then you may end up doing unnecessary work (e.g., if you branch on x when PLE would give you ~x).  Of course, a sensible branching heuristic will give you PLE anyway.  I'm curious, have I made an error in my description of UP?

Comment: @Rafe: actually, no, you're correct, now that I look at standard definitions of them, I guess I don't usually explain the two outside of each other, but nope, you're right!

Comment: @KristopherMicinski: phew, that's a relief: I used to lecture this stuff!

Comment: @Rafe me too, but I hadn't looked at my slides in a while :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Davis–Putnam–Logemann–Loveland (DPLL) algorithm is a, backtracking-based search algorithm for deciding the satisfiability of propositional logic formulae in conjunctive normal form also known as satisfiability problem or SAT.

Any boolean formula can be expressed in conjunctive normal form (CNF) which means a conjunction of clauses i.e. ( … ) ^ ( … ) ^ ( … )

where a clause is a disjunction of boolean variables i.e. ( A v B v C’ v D)

an example of boolean formula expressed in CNF is

(A v B v C) ^ (C’ v D) ^ (D’ v A)

and solving the SAT problem means finding the combination of values for the variables in the formula that satisfy it like A=1, B=0, C=0, D=0

This is a NP-Complete problem. Actually it is the first problem which has been proven to be NP-Complete by Stepehn Cook and Leonid Levin

A particular type of SAT problem is the 3-SAT which is a SAT in which all clauses have three variables.

The DPLL algorithm is way to solve SAT problem (which practically depends on the hardness of the input) that recursively creates a tree of potential solution

Suppose you want to solve a 3-SAT problem like this

(A v B v C) ^ (C’ v D v B) ^ (B v A’ v C) ^ (C’ v A’ v B’)

if we enumerate the variables like A=1 B=2 C=3 D=4 and se negative numbers for negated variables like A’ = -1 then the same formula can be written in Python like this

[[1,2,3],[-3,4,2],[2,-1,3],[-3,-1,-2]]

now imagine to create a tree in which each node consists of a partial solution. In our example we also depicted a vector of the clauses satisfied by the solution

the root node is [-1,-1,-1,-1] which means no values have been yet assigned to the variables neither 0 nor 1

at each iteration:

1. we take the first unsatisfied clause then
2. if there are no more unassigned variables we can use to satisfy that clause then there can’t be valid solutions in this branch of the search tree and the algorithm shall return None
3. otherwise we take the first unassigned variable and set it such it satisfies the clause and start recursively from step 1. If the inner invocation of the algorithm returns None we flip the value of the variable so that it does not satisfy the clause and set the next unassigned variable in order to satisfy the clause. If all the three variables have been tried or there are no more unassigned variable for that clause it means there are no valid solutions in this branch and the algorithm shall return None

See the following example:

from the root node we choose the first variable (A) of the first clause (A v B v C) and set it such it satisfies the clause then A=1 (second node of the search tree)

the continue with the second clause and we pick the first unassigned variable (C) and set it such it satisfies the clause which means C=0 (third node on the left)

we do the same thing for the fourth clause (B v A’ v C) and set B to 1

we try to do the same thing for the last clause we realize we no longer have unassigned variables and the clause is always false. We then have to backtrack to the previous position in the search tree. We change the value we assigned to B and set B to 0. Then we look for another unassigned value that can satisfy the third clause but there are not. Then we have to backtrack again to the second node

Once there we have to flip the assignment of the first variable (C) so that it won’t satisfy the clause and set the next unassigned variable (D) in order to satisfy it (i.e. C=1 and D=1). This also satisfies the third clause which contains C.

The last clause to satisfy (C’ v A’ v B’)  has one unassigned variable B which can be then set to 0 in order to satisfy the clause.

[image]

In this link http://lowcoupling.com/post/72424308422/a-simple-3-sat-solver-using-dpll you can find also the python code implementing it